# No GPS position with Google Maps on Galaxy Nexus with android 4.0.4

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps

I tried to use Google Maps online and it's not possible to find my location. The App Google Maps works perfect. I tried Firefox 14 and Chrome 18.

I'm asking because I want to develop with html5 and google maps and have issues with finding the position.

Does somebody know whats this about, I never looked into it.

Thanks soo far!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why. However, you can create an LocationListener class to keep track of user's location. You then create interface for web to call using javascript. This way you can access to user's location from website using the phone hardware. This implementation is described in one of Commonsware's book.

Comment: There are these HTML 5 features. They are very easy and nice. They should work with a Galaxy Nexus. Shouldn't they? Maybe if have some settings to change, but I don't know.